# Feature Selection in PySpark

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, feature-selection, google-cloud-dataproc

I am working on a machine learning model of shape `1,456,354 X 53`. I wanted to do feature selection for my data set. I know how to do feature selection in `python` using the following code.

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV,RFE

logreg = LogisticRegression()
rfe = RFE(logreg, step=1, n_features_to_select=28)
rfe = rfe.fit(df.values,arrythmia.values)
features_bool = np.array(rfe.support_)
features = np.array(df.columns)
result = features[features_bool]
print(result)
```

However, I could not find any article which could show how can I perform recursive feature selection in `pyspark`.

I tried to import `sklearn` libraries in pyspark but it gave me an error sklearn module not found.  I am running pyspark on google dataproc cluster.

Could please someone help me achieve this in pyspark

Comment: Good question. I am wondering the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can try following **feature selection** methods in **pyspark**

- Chi-Squared selector
- Randomforest selector

References:

- https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-features.html#feature-selectors
- https://databricks.com/session/building-custom-ml-pipelinestages-for-feature-selection

Answer (score 7):

You have a few options for doing this.

- If the model you need is implemented in either Spark's `MLlib` or spark-sklearn`, you can adapt your code to use the corresponding library.
- If you can train your model locally and just want to deploy it to make predictions, you can use User Defined Functions (`UDFs`) or [`vectorized UDFs`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf) to run the trained model on Spark. [Here's](https://medium.com/civis-analytics/prediction-at-scale-with-scikit-learn-and-pyspark-pandas-udfs-51d5ebfb2cd8) a good post discussing how to do this.
- If you need to run an `sklearn` model on Spark that is not supported by spark-sklearn, you'll need to make sklearn available to Spark on each worker node in your cluster. You can do this by manually installing sklearn on each node in your Spark cluster (make sure you are installing into the Python environment that Spark is using).
- Alternatively, you can package and distribute the sklearn library with the `Pyspark` job. In short, you can `pip install sklearn` into a local directory near your script, then zip the sklearn installation directory and use the `--py-files` flag of `spark-submit` to send the zipped sklearn to all workers along with your script. [This article](https://developerzen.com/best-practices-writing-production-grade-pyspark-jobs-cb688ac4d20f) has a complete overview of how to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks Jerry,  I would try installing sklearn on each worker node in my cluster

Answer (score 2):

I suggest with stepwise regression model you can easily find the important features and only that dataset them in logistics regression. Stepwise regression works on correlation but it has variations.
Below link will help to implement stepwise regression for feature selection.
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24405/how-to-do-stepwise-regression-using-sklearn